# String generator algorithm VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, algorithm

I'm making Visual Basic program and i need one specific algorithm for it.
I my function(or timer or whatever...) to return

```
> a
> b
> ...
> z
> A
> ...
> Z
> 0
> ...
> 9
> aa
> ab
> ..
> az
> aA
> ...
> aZ
```

etc.

Thank you in advance for any replies.

Comment: If you need a function, you should write it - SO is not a code-outsourcing service. If you run into _specific_ problems with your function, you're welcome to post it (with the code) and you'll likely receive help.

Comment: An alternative to the given answers which use a hard-coded alphabet, you can do something in code with ASC, CHR, and for-Next loops - if this is a homework question, it may be that this is the approach they're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Private Function Test() As String
    Const Letters As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Const Numbers As String = "0123456789"
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    For iLetter = 0 To Letters.Length - 1
        sb.Append(Letters(iLetter)).AppendLine()
    Next

    For iNumbers = 0 To Numbers.Length - 1
        sb.Append(Numbers(iNumbers)).AppendLine()
    Next

    For xLetter = 0 To Letters.Length - 1
        For yLetter = 0 To Letters.Length - 1
            sb.Append(Letters(xLetter) & Letters(yLetter)).AppendLine()
        Next
    Next
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the Microsoft Reactive Framework team's Interactive Extensions (NuGet "Ix-Main") as it gives you a very handy function `EnumerableEx.Expand`. You can use it like this:

```
Dim alphabet = "abcABC01"

Dim Query = EnumerableEx.Expand(
    alphabet.Select(Function (x) x.ToString()),
    Function (y) alphabet.Select(Function (x) y & x.ToString()))
```

This produces an infinite sequence. You need to do `Query.Take(n)` for some number of `n` that you want to generate for the sequence to stop.

So I can do `String.Join(", ", Query.Take(100))` which gives me this:

> a, b, c, A, B, C, 0, 1, aa, ab, ac, aA, aB, aC, a0, a1, ba, bb, bc, bA, bB, bC, b0, b1, ca, cb, cc, cA, cB, cC, c0, c1, Aa, Ab, Ac, AA, AB, AC, A0, A1, Ba, Bb, Bc, BA, BB, BC, B0, B1, Ca, Cb, Cc, CA, CB, CC, C0, C1, 0a, 0b, 0c, 0A, 0B, 0C, 00, 01, 1a, 1b, 1c, 1A, 1B, 1C, 10, 11, aaa, aab, aac, aaA, aaB, aaC, aa0, aa1, aba, abb, abc, abA, abB, abC, ab0, ab1, aca, acb, acc, acA, acB, acC, ac0, ac1, aAa, aAb, aAc, aAA

It would be easy for you to put in your full alphabet.